# Can't find a range of maximum product subarray

Tags: c++

I'm solving Maximum Product Subarray problem on C++. My code finds only a max.product of subarray, but not a range.

I found some explanation here - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-product-subarray/ and used the code. How could I find the range(Left index, Right index) of subarray that gives me maximum product? (I found some similar posts here, but all of them on java, and i can't understand them properly)

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int min(int x, int y) {
   return (x < y) ? x : y;
}

int max(int x, int y) {
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
}

int solve(int a[], int n){
    int maxend = 0, minend = 0;
    int maxans = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        int temp = maxend;
        maxend = max(a[i], max(a[i] * maxend, a[i] * minend));
        minend = min(a[i], min(a[i] * temp, a[i] * minend));
        maxans = max(maxans, maxend);
    }
    return maxans;
}

int main(void){
    int n, a[10000];
    cin >> n;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    cout << solve(a, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the range information, you can keep track of the indices where `maxans` variable changed. That would indicate to you where the maximum product comes from, which would be the right endpoint of the range. Then, after you compute the `maxans`, you can basically go left until you get the maximum product, at which point you will have found the left interval.

The following implementation can serve as a demonstration.

```
int solve(int a[], int n){
    int maxend = 0, minend = 0;
    int maxans = 0;

    int max_r = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        int temp = maxend;
        maxend = max(a[i], max(a[i] * maxend, a[i] * minend));
        minend = min(a[i], min(a[i] * temp, a[i] * minend));
        if(maxans < maxend){
            maxans = maxend;
            max_r = i;
        }
    }

    int max_l = max_r;
    for(int i=1; i < maxans; max_l--){
        i = i * a[max_l];
    }

    //At this point you have the range [max_l, max_r] that yield maxans as the product
    return maxans;
}
```